After installing app libraries in Docker Container with UV - app don't see those libraries
I have a Flask app, which running in Docker.
All running good.
Now I'm trying to switch from PIP to UV.
Container building no problem and showing all packages inside, but when I try to run this container - app don't see libraries.
My Dockerfile look like this:
FROM python:3.9

COPY --from=ghcr.io/astral-sh/uv:latest /uv /uvx /bin/

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN uv venv --python 3.9 && uv sync --frozen

EXPOSE 5100
CMD ["python", "app.py"]

My pyproject.toml super simple:
[project]
name = "bgrm"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Add your description here"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.9"
dependencies = [
    "flask>=3.1.0",
    "pillow>=9.3.0",
    "rembg==2.0.30",
]

When I run container I have:
2024-12-14 23:11:35 Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-12-14 23:11:35   File "/app/app.py", line 3, in <module>
2024-12-14 23:11:35     from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_file
2024-12-14 23:11:35 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

Only difference I found between containers:
In PIP-based Flask locations are:
/app/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask-3.1.0.dist-info/METADATA
/app/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask-3.1.0.dist-info/RECORD
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask-3.1.0.dist-info/METADATA
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask-3.1.0.dist-info/RECORD

In UV-based Flask locations are:
/app/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask-3.1.0.dist-info/METADATA
/app/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask-3.1.0.dist-info/RECORD

Seems I still lacking understanding on how UV perform sync.
Have no idea what's wrong.
Update:
This morning, I found a solution. And I think I even understand why it's working this way.
I read some old manuals about running venv in Docker.
Then, modified Docker like that:
CMD [".venv/bin/python", "app.py]
Why this works:

uv create .venv folder by default
uv scan machine for Python interpreters and find 3.9
uv pin 3.9 interpreter to the venv
uv sync libraries to the .venv
when I run command with normal python - libraries not there


Don't you want to use uv run instead of python in your CMD? CMD ["uv","run","app,py"]

Personally, I prefer using ENTRYPOINT to CMD.

I read this article https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-best-practices-choosing-between-run-cmd-and-entrypoint/ and got the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT. In my case, ENTRYPOINT is better use. And your suggestion for ["uv", "run", "app.py"] worked fine as well. Thank you.
